# ReactJS: setState using if else

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. On my index page, the initial state of loginState & modalStatus is false. I am trying to change modalStatus to true inside componentDidMount().

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      modalStatus: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
      this.setState({ modalStatus: true});
      console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
    }  else {
        console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <h1>Hello</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

But my console is printing false for both modalStatus even after setState. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please guide me. I would appreciate any helps.

Comment: It seems that you are not closing `componentDidMount()`, after if-else block add one **}**

Comment: `this.setState({ modalStatus: true}, console.log(this.state.modalStatus))` will console.log the correct value. Also fyi, if else is not a loop

Comment: mybad :( I will update question

Answer (score 5):

SetState is asynchronous so when you do setState the modifies value won’t be available immediately. In order to see updated state value

Change

```
  componentDidMount() {
if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
  console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
  this.setState({ modalStatus: true});
  console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
}  else {
    console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
}
}
```

To

```
 componentDidMount() {
if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
  console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
  this.setState({ modalStatus: true}, () => {
       console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
  });
}  else {
    console.log(this.state.modalStatus);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes made via `setState()` will not be immediately reflected. It is an asynchronous function. Try logging it inside `render()` you can see the new value.

NOTE: you should not leave the console.log() inside render function, as it will impact performance